# Abstract argumentation theory. Why is this not a grounded extension?

Tags: argumentation

[image: argumentation screencap]

[image: args screencap 2]

So the first two slides explain abstract argumentation theory and the last shows some examples.

In the second example why is {a1} not a grounded extension? There is no element in the argument graph which is a proper subset of a1, so it is minimal. A minimal set of arguments is grounded. So {a1} should be grounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the empty set **{ }** is complete and it is a subset of both **{A1}** and **{A2}** and thus they are not grounded because not complete **and** minimal.

Comment: Then doesn’t that mean no set of arguments can be grounded? Since no matter what the empty set will always be a subset of the chosen argument set.

Comment: @Shiny_and_Chrome - yes but... in Ex.1 the empty set is **not** complete while in Ex.2 it is.

Comment: Ah... I think I just figured out why. In the first example the emtpy set is not complete because the empty set "defends" A3, as it is not attacked by anything. Meaning that defended(gamma) = gamma doesn't hold.

Whereas in the second example it does, since there is not any argument which is not attacked.